# How can I disable this box on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've searched through similar questions, and couldn't find an answer. It's that box that keeps opening whenever I push Enter, and proceed to include another style component on my stylesheet.
Most of the times it covers a lot of the code when it appears, and this is kinda bothering me. Thanks in advance!

[image: Image of the box]

Answer (score 0):

You could stop quick suggestions by adding the following snippet in settings.json

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}
```

Or if you just want to disable only emmet abbreviations, you could do so by adding this property in settings.json

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
```

More information about various intellisense and emmet abbreviations settings could be found in the following pages

- [VS Code intellisense settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)
- [VS Code Emmet settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)